# django form.is_valid returns false when while using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, django-forms, xmlhttprequest

since bootstrap 5 no longer ships with jquery and recommends using the vanilla javascript XMLHttpRequest() to make dynamic requests that is what I am trying to do in django. All the other examples of doing this use the traditional .$ajax.
I have a basic javascript function:

```
function sendPhoneVerification(_phone) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const params = {
            phone: _phone
    }
    http.open('POST', '/approvephone/', true)
    http.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ csrf_token }}");
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
    http.setRequestHeader('phone', _phone)
    http.send(JSON.stringify(params))
    http.onload = function() {
        alert(http.responseText)
    }
}
```

The CSRF middlware token is working fine, but the in the view, the form.is_valid() returns false and the error is that required field "phone" is missing. I can't tell how I am supposed to provide that value. The form being tested against is a simple form with one field

```
class AddPhoneForm(forms.Form):
    phone = PhoneNumberField()
```

relevant part of the view

```
@csrf_protect
@login_required
def approvephone(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddPhoneForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid()  #returns false and error is missing field "phone"
```

Any idea how I can correctly provide the phone fields in the POST response to make django happy?

Answer (score 0):

ok I feel stupid, but in django you need to send 'Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' as described here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send

```
function sendPhoneVerification(_phone) {
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!" + _phone);
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('POST', '/approvephone/', true)
    http.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ csrf_token }}");
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    http.send("phone="+_phone)

    http.onload = function() {
        alert(http.responseText)
    }
```